# Installing fwbackups recipe for target failed

Tags: make

I am trying to install fwbackups, and I've been following the [documentation](http://www.diffingo.com/oss/fwbackups/documentation/installation). But I can't install the program.

These are the steps I've followed

```
sudo apt-get install gettext autotools-dev intltool python-crypto python-paramiko python-gtk2 python-glade2 python-notify cron
tar xfj fwbackups-1.43.6.tar.bz2
cd fwbackups-1.43.6
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install
```

Here is the console ouput

```
gaston@127:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install gettext autotools-dev intltool python-crypto python-paramiko python-gtk2 python-glade2 python-notify cron

sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1localhost.localdomainlocalhost: Resource temporarily unavailable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
autotools-dev is already the newest version (20160430.1).
cron is already the newest version (3.0pl1-128ubuntu2).
gettext is already the newest version (0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2).
intltool is already the newest version (0.51.0-2).
python-crypto is already the newest version (2.6.1-6build1).
python-glade2 is already the newest version (2.24.0-4ubuntu1).
python-gtk2 is already the newest version (2.24.0-4ubuntu1).
python-paramiko is already the newest version (2.0.0-1).
python-notify is already the newest version (0.1.1-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.

gaston@127:~/Downloads$ tar xfj fwbackups-1.43.6.tar.bz2

gaston@127:~/Downloads$ cd fwbackups-1.43.6

gaston@127:~/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6$ ./configure --prefix=/usr

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.4... python
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.35.0... 0.51.0 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.22.2
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating bin/Makefile
config.status: creating bin/fwbackups
config.status: creating pixmaps/Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/fwbackups/Makefile
config.status: creating src/fwbackups/operations/Makefile
config.status: creating src/fwbackups/__init__.py
config.status: creating src/fwbackups/const.py
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating fwbackups.spec
config.status: executing po/stamp-it commands
```

Finally, it fails at this point:

```
gaston@127:~/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6$ make && sudo make install
Making all in bin
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/bin'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/bin'
Making all in po
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/po'
file=`echo de | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file de.po
file=`echo gl | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file gl.po
file=`echo hr | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file hr.po
file=`echo is | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file is.po
file=`echo lt | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file lt.po
file=`echo ms | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ms.po
file=`echo oc | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file oc.po
file=`echo ru | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ru.po
file=`echo sv | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file sv.po
file=`echo th | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file th.po
file=`echo uk | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file uk.po
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/po'
Making all in pixmaps
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/pixmaps'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/pixmaps'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src'
Making all in src/fwbackups/operations
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
Making all in src/fwbackups
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6'
sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1localhost.localdomainlocalhost: Resource temporarily unavailable
Making install in bin
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/bin'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/bin'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
/bin/bash /home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/install-sh -d /usr/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 fwbackups /usr/bin/fwbackups
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 fwbackups-run.py /usr/bin/fwbackups-run
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 fwbackups-runonce.py /usr/bin/fwbackups-runonce
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/bin'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/bin'
Making install in po
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/po'
linguas="de gl hr is lt ms oc ru sv th uk "; \
for lang in $linguas; do \
  dir=/usr/share/locale/$lang/LC_MESSAGES; \
  /bin/bash /home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/install-sh -d $dir; \
  if test -r $lang.gmo; then \
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $lang.gmo $dir/fwbackups.mo; \
    echo "installing $lang.gmo as $dir/fwbackups.mo"; \
  else \
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$lang.gmo $dir/fwbackups.mo; \
    echo "installing ./$lang.gmo as" \
     "$dir/fwbackups.mo"; \
  fi; \
  if test -r $lang.gmo.m; then \
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $lang.gmo.m $dir/fwbackups.mo.m; \
    echo "installing $lang.gmo.m as $dir/fwbackups.mo.m"; \
  else \
    if test -r ./$lang.gmo.m ; then \
      /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$lang.gmo.m \
    $dir/fwbackups.mo.m; \
      echo "installing ./$lang.gmo.m as" \
       "$dir/fwbackups.mo.m"; \
    else \
      true; \
    fi; \
  fi; \
done
installing de.gmo as /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing gl.gmo as /usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing hr.gmo as /usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing is.gmo as /usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing lt.gmo as /usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing ms.gmo as /usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing oc.gmo as /usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing ru.gmo as /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing sv.gmo as /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing th.gmo as /usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
installing uk.gmo as /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/fwbackups.mo
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/po'
Making install in pixmaps
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/pixmaps'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/pixmaps'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
/bin/bash /home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/install-sh -d /usr/share/icons/hicolor/{scalable,128x128,64x64,48x48,32x32,16x16}/apps/
/bin/bash /home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/install-sh -d /usr/share/fwbackups/
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/fwbackups.svg
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups-128.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/fwbackups.png
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups-64.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/fwbackups.png
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups-48.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/fwbackups.png
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups-32.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/fwbackups.png
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups-16.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/fwbackups.png
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups-32.png /usr/share/fwbackups/fwbackups.png
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/pixmaps'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/pixmaps'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
/bin/bash /home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/install-sh -d /usr/share/applications
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fwbackups.desktop /usr/share/applications/fwbackups.desktop
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/fwbackups'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 BugReport.glade fwbackups.glade fwbackups-autostart.desktop fwbackups-runapp.pyw '/usr/share/fwbackups'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src'
Making install in src/fwbackups/operations
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups/operations'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups’: File exists
Makefile:293: recipe for target 'install-pyPYTHON' failed
make[2]: *** [install-pyPYTHON] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
Makefile:390: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
Makefile:375: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

error message:

```
Makefile:293: recipe for target 'install-pyPYTHON' failed
make[2]: *** [install-pyPYTHON] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
Makefile:390: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
Makefile:375: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I've been searching for similar errors but I could not find anything relevant

Comment: It looks like `/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups/operations'` fails because `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups` is a file instead of a directory. Perhaps try `sudo rm /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups` and then try the install again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a malformed line in your `/etc/hosts` file - this causes the `sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1localhost.localdomainlocalhost: Resource temporarily unavailable` messages (and may cause other problems). There must be <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters between the IP address and the hostname, e.g:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Fix this first.

Then, the

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/gaston/Downloads/fwbackups-1.43.6/src/fwbackups/operations'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups/operations'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups’: File exists

Makefile:293: recipe for target 'install-pyPYTHON' failed
```

(and these are the useful lines from your log dump) messages tell us that some other package, or some earlier attempt to install this package, has created a directory that this install counts on being able to create.

See if the package management system knows about the directory with `dpkg -S /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups`, read the `README` file and the `Makefile` to see if a `make clean` or `make uninstall` might be appropriate.

If you're willing to use the brute force approach (I do NOT recommend this), and risk the health of your system's packaging system, you could

```
sudo rmdir /usr/lib/python2.7/distpackages/fwbackups
```

If the `rmdir` complains that the directory isn't empty, investigate what's in there, then (again, mind the risk)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/distpackages/fwbackups
```

Comment: It finally worked, thanks, by the way, its 'sudo rmdir /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups' :D